# Assigning a constant with multiple words to a variable?

Tags: c++

I'm brand new to programming and I'm having some trouble. I want be able to input a first and last name, and depending on what name is entered into the program, elicit different responses. For example: if the user inputs "Bruce Wayne" I want the program to say "You are Batman". But if the user inputs " Clarke Kent" I want the program to respond with "You are Superman". The problem is trying to assign the constants "Bruce Wayne" and "Clarke Kent" to a variable that can work with cin>> . Can someone help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by "variable that can work with cin>>"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, name );

    if ( name == "Bruce Wayne" ) std::cout << "You are Batman" << std::endl; 
    else if ( name == "Clarke Kent" ) std::cout << "You are Superman".<< std::endl; 
    else std::cout << "You are impostor".<< std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: I think it will be better to use `compare`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: @user473973 It is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use constants.

1. Get user input
2. If user input is "Bruce Wayne" output "You are Batman"
3. If user input is "Clark Kent" output "You are Superman"